# Repeat table headers with UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm printing using the UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter and I can't seem to get table headers to repeat on every page. Here's the HTML I'm currently testing with:

```
@"<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">"
"<head>"
"<title>KegID Manifest</title>"
"<style type=\"text/css\">"
" thead {display: table-header-group;}"
"</style>"
"</head>"
"<body>"
"<table><thead><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr></thead>"
"<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>"
"<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>"
...repeated 200 times
"<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>"
"</table></body></html>"
```

Is there a better method for repeating table headers with UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter or do I need to switch away from using HTML?

Comment: Have you found a solution?